# Asymptote in LaTeX - a peculiar problem

Tags: asymptote

I wonder if someone can explain what follows to me and how to remedy it. The following piece of Asymptote code:

```
import graph;
import graph3;

currentprojection=perspective(4,5,5);

real f(pair z) {return z.x^2-z.y^2;}
triple c(real t) {return (cos(t),sin(t),f((cos(t),sin(t))));}
triple n(real t) {triple w=cross((1,0,2*cos(t)),(0,1,-2*sin(t))); return unit(w);}

picture pic;
size(pic,150,150,IgnoreAspect);

draw(pic,surface(f,(-2,-2),(2,2),nx=10,Spline),green,render(merge=true));

draw(pic,graph(c,0,2*pi,operator ..),red+2);

picture pic2;
size(pic2,150);

draw(pic2,unitsphere,opacity(0.1));

draw(pic2,graph(n,0,2*pi,operator ..),red+2);

int antal=10;
for(int i=0;i < antal;++i){
real t=2*pi*i/antal;

draw(pic,shift(c(t))*((0,0,0)--n(t)),blue+1,Arrow3);

draw(pic2,(0,0,0)--n(t),blue+1,Arrow3);
}

add(pic.fit(),(0,0),W);
add(pic2.fit(),(20mm,0),E);
```

works fine when I run it through Asymptote. It gives me two pictures, call them A and B, side by side.

If I now include the code in an asy-environment in my LaTeX-document a peculiar thing happens: I get two copies of B side by side. If I change the order of the add-commands at the end I get two copies of A instead.

Why do I not get A and B, as when I run it alone?

The code above is inserted into a LaTeX-file that looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\title{A test example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}  
\maketitle  
\section{Introduction}  
Some introductory text.  
\begin{center}  
\begin{asy}[inline=true]  
CODE  
\end{asy}  
\end{center}  
More text  
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see a complete (non)-working `.tex` file. For instance, do you use the `inline` option when including the `asymptote` package?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\title{A test example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Some introductory text.

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}[inline=true]

Comment: sorry CODE\end{asy}
\end{center}

More text
\end{document}

Comment: You should be able to edit the question itself.

Comment: If you remove the two instances of `inline`, it will solve this problem. (Of course, there may be other reasons you want to use `inline`, which is why I'm making this a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: Thanks. If I only understood the meaning of the inline option...

Comment: I think its purpose is to make packages and macros defined in your latex file available inside labels in the `asy` environments. But it seems to have other effects as well. A number of questions asked on this sight have been solved by saying either "add the `inline` option" or "remove the `inline` option."